# Get stabilized pitch and roll values

Tags: android, jmonkeyengine, pitch, android-augmented-reality

I want to get best pitch and roll values.
I'm already using that code to get azimut value.

Pitch and roll values seem not be good.

```
@Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        switch (event.sensor.getType()) {

            case Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR:
                // calculate th rotation matrix
                SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(rMat, event.values);

                float[] data = SensorManager.getOrientation(rMat, orientation);

                Log.i(TAG, "NEW pitch?="+data[1]+" roll="+data[2]);

                // do something with data

                break;
        }
```

I'm using that code in augmented reality environment (with Jmonkey engine) to move 3d objects depending on phone position :

```
public void updateRotationFused(float pitch, float roll) {
    //pitch: cams x axis roll: cams y axisheading: cams z axis
    mRotXYZQ.fromAngles(pitch + FastMath.HALF_PI , roll - FastMath.HALF_PI, 0);
    mCurrentCamRotationFused = mInitialCamRotation.mult(mRotXYZQ);
}
```

Is something I missed ?

**EDIT**

Code already in use in app is from this [link](https://github.com/TKJElectronics/BalanduinoAndroidApp/blob/master/src/com/tkjelectronics/balanduino/SensorFusion.java)

It works but I think `Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR` is a better way.

Comment: How are the values 'not good'? Are they noisy?

Answer (score 0):

Accelerometers in mobile phones tend to be quite noisy and you need to apply a filter to get better results.
This could be anything from a [trimmed mean filter](http://www.librow.com/articles/article-7/appendix-a-2) to a [Kalman filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter)
I suggest starting with a mean filter as it is pretty straight-forward to implement. Simply put it will cut off values too far from the most common ones based on a "window" size.